# Workflow Manager Auto Generated Certificates

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow

I have SharePoint Farm with 2 Web front end servers, 2 application servers, and Database server. I have installed and configure Workflow manager on one of the application server with auto generated certificates.I have added one the certificate to SharePoint Server which host Central admin by going to the SharePoint Management shell and running the New-SPTrustedRootAuthority cmdlet.Do I have to add all four certificates from workflow manager server to all SharePoint servers in a farm? Please advise.

Thanks
Ronak

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install the certificate on all servers, this command will add it on required location. You can add the same certificate via central admin. Check this TechNet wiki which explains it.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34451.sharepoint-2016-step-by-step-guide-to-add-workflow-manager-certificate-into-sharepoint-trust.aspx

Comment: Thanks Waqas for your reply. This is exactly what i did during configuration. I have followed your blog and Harber.net blog to configure Workflow Manager. I am getting below error message.• An operation failed because the following certificate has validation errors:  Subject Name: CN=WorkflowOutbound Issuer Name: CN=WorkflowOutbound Thumbprint: Guid  Errors:   The root of the certificate chain is not a trusted root authority.
•Request for security token failed with exception: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized

Comment: have u tried to manually copy the certs on trusted root authority on the server where u are getting error.

Comment: Not Yet Waqas but we are going to do this COB today. I will post my finding on this thread. Thanks

Comment: We have exported certificate on workflow manager server using Get-WFAutoGeneratedCA and added this certificate to Trusted Root Certification Authorities on client machines(WFEs). Also add certificate to SharePoint using New-SPTrustedRootAuthority. I did not see any errors as of now and still monitoring the workflow instances. Thanks.